# Oledb reader does not read excel files correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, oledb

I am trying to read a xls file through OLEDB reader, with mixed datatype in one column of xls. Oledb returns me DBNULL for these column Values. i have `05-06-12` in first cell of this column. when i goes for checking format cell, it shows  me `custom type with dd-mm-yy` and in all other cells it shows General format. I am using following connection string

```
mCon.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + mstrFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";");
```

I have following data in xls

- 05-06-12
- 'abc'
- '56565'

OLEDB Reads it like this

- 05-Jun-12
- DBNULL
- DBNULL

What could be the reason ? Even i put `IMEX = 1` in connection string !!!

Comment: Is the data literally `'abc'` in the cell, or is it actually just `abc` (without the single quotes)?

Comment: Also, please post the code you are using to read out the data.

Comment: After having done some testing on my own, I cannot reproduce your results.  I tried `'abc'`, `''abc'` (what was required to actually _see_ `'abc'` displayed in the Excel data cell), and `abc`.  Regardless of using an `OleDbDataAdapter` selecting into a `DataSet` via the `Fill` method, or by looping through using an `OleDbDataReader`, I always get the correct values read out.  I suspect there is something specific about the formatting in your Excel sheet that is causing this.

Comment: Further, I suspect that if the first cell of the column in question holds the date (`05-06-12`), then the column's `DataType` is being defined by the format of that cell, making the data that follow invalid against that type.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when reading xlsx files. I changed my connection string to the following and it worked:

```
const string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xlsx;" +"Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
```

You need to convert your xls to xlsx and use

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

to read the xlsx file.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Importmixedtypes=text` to your connecton string like this

```
mCon.ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Importmixedtypes=text;typeguessrows=0;\"",mstrFilePath);
```

Comment: Can you Post first few rows of your excel sheet?

Comment: I had posted sample data in my question

Comment: I cannot test from these three data. Post atleast four rows of your excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of trial and error and searching for the solution, I got working with this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= {0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=2;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""
```

**Note:**

1. IMEX = 2
2. HDR = YES, and most importantly
3. Extended Properties should be enclosed with double quote

Sorry this is not working too...used wrong file :-(

Answer (score -1):

I guess your connection string is wrong. If the Excel version is 2007 or higher (i.e. .xlsx extension), then we need to use ACE engine else in case of xls file (in your case), we should use the Jet engine connection string. Please replace the below mentioned string with your existing one. I guess the problem should get solved.

```
mCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                  "Data Source=" + FilePath + ";" +
                  "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1' ";
```